# Trying to add a config file via a volume - file not showing in expected directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In my docker compose I have:

- ${PROJECTS_DIR:-~/Projects/Zen/rstudio-prefs.json}:/home/.config/rstudio/rstudio-prefs.json

Then, in my Makefile I have:

```
export PROJECTS_DIR ?= ~/Projects/Zen

.PHONY: build
build:
        docker-compose build

.PHONY: up
up:
        docker-compose pull
        docker-compose up -d

.PHONY: restart
restart:
        docker-compose restart

.PHONY: down
down:
        docker-compose down
```

On my local laptop where I'm running docker I have a file called `rstudio-prefs.json`. I would like to add this file to the running container so that it appears in `/home/rstudio/.config/rstudio`.

When I run `make build` and then `make up` I am able t enter the container however the file `rstudio-prefs.json` does not appear as expected.

How can I add ~/Projects/Zen/ide-rstudio/rstudio-prefs.json from local to the container in /home/.config/rstudio-prefs.json ?

Per comment, here is my entire docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  ide-rstudio:
    image: rocker/verse:latest
    ports:
      - 8787:8787
      - 3838:3838
    environment:
      PASSWORD: test
      ROOT: "TRUE"
      ADD: "shiny"
    volumes:
      - ${PROJECTS_DIR:-~/Projects/Zen}:/home/rstudio/Projects
      - ${PROJECTS_DIR:-~/Projects/Zen/ide-rstudio/rstudio-prefs.json}:/home/.config/rstudio/rstudio-prefs.json
```

Comment: Please, post part of your `docker-compose.yml` file where at least minimal parts of the service definition are shown, not just the "failing" volume line. Posting complete service is ok if you have no problems sharing it.

Comment: Hi @emi I have added this now. If you see anything that is incorrect, please do let me know

Comment: I have tested (with minimal modifications) and it works. The only not tested thing is the value of the env var `PROJECTS_DIR`. Could you post it?

Comment: From within the running container I tried `echo $PROJECTS_DIR` and this returned nothing. So I guess this narrows it down?

Comment: This variable should/can be defined in the host, where the `docker-compose.yml` file resides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mount the full directory instead of just the file. Sometimes, image layers may have some unexpected behavior.

Just modified a bit the `docker-compose.yml` to narrow the problems and obtained a successful result (`PROJECTS_DIR` is undefined in my system):

`docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: "3.5"
services:
  ide-rstudio:
    image: rocker/verse:latest
    stdin_open: true
    command: "bash"
    environment:
      PASSWORD: test
      ROOT: "TRUE"
      ADD: "shiny"
    volumes:
      - ${PROJECTS_DIR:-~/Projects/test-rstudio}:/home/rstudio/Projects
      - ${PROJECTS_DIR:-~/Projects/Zen/ide-rstudio/}:/home/.config/rstudio/
```

File is mounted correctly:

```
$ pwd
/home/myuser/Projects/test-rstudio
$ docker-compose up -d
$ docker-compose exec ide-rstudio ls -l /home/rstudio/Projects /home/.config/rstudio
/home/.config/rstudio:
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000 17 Nov  7 18:58 rstudio-prefs.json

/home/rstudio/Projects:
total 8
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000  395 Nov  7 19:01 docker-compose.yml
drwxrwxr-x 2 1000 1000 4096 Nov  7 18:58 ide-rstudio

$ cat ide-rstudio/rstudio-prefs.json 
{"hello":"world"}
$ docker-compose exec ide-rstudio cat /home/.config/rstudio/rstudio-prefs.json
{"hello":"world"}
```

#### Edit

Changed `docker-compose.yml` back to use `rocker/verse` instead of `ubuntu`.

#### Edit 2

Changed the `docker-compose.yml` to reflect successful response: `You can mount the full directory instead of just the file. Sometimes, image layers may have some unexpected behavior.`

Comment: Wait though, because a file with the same name is installed there by default. My goal is to overwrite the rstudio-prefs.json file with my saved one, as opposed to a brand new out of the box config

Comment: I added $PROJECTS_DIR to my .bashrc on local. `echo $PROJECTS_DIR
/home/myname/Projects` however in the container $PROJECTS_DIR is still not showing any set value

Comment: Updated the answer using the original `rocker/verse` image. Same successful results.

Comment: `however in the container $PROJECTS_DIR is still not showing any set value`: If you don't define it somewhere in the container pipeline (Dockerfile, docker-compose, .env, entrypoint, ...), its not expected to be defined in the container.

Comment: Seems when I include `command: "bash"` in docker-compose the rstudio ide does not load on localhost:8787. When you run are you able to see the ide in your browser at localhost:8787? I kept the ports part from my docker-compose (tried without them too). Still no success. Thanks for trying all the same :/

Comment: No, this is because I don't have this extra JSON file contents, neither the full project, but I can see it is correctly mounted using the same container image. `command: "bash"` changes the command executed when initializing the container.

Comment: You can mount the full directory instead of just the file. Sometimes, image layers may have some unexpected behavior:
`- ${PROJECTS_DIR:-~/Projects/Zen/ide-rstudio/}:/home/.config/rstudio/`

Comment: @DougFir If this was helpful, please, also up vote it.